# JavaFx editable tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am trying to write a simple application that retrieves data from DB and writes back to DB. I use javafx, I am trying to list my data in a tableview and be able to edit into it. But could not make editable option work. Please see below for the error explanation. It gives error here.

```
id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());//It gives error here.



public class Person {

    private int id;


     public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

}

public class PersonController 
{
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personGrid;

    private ObservableList<Person> dataPerson;  
    dataPerson = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Person person;

    try {
        statement = dbConnection.connectToDB().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT ID FROM PERSON");

        ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery();
        while (queryResult.next()) {
            person = new Person();
            person.setId(queryResult.getInt("id"));
            dataPerson.add(person);
        }
        personGrid.setItems(dataPerson);        


    personGrid.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn<Person, Integer> id = new TableColumn("ID");
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("id"));
        id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn()); 
// Here I get the error  javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<org.core.Person, java.lang.Integer>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<org.core.Person, java.lang.Integer>>
                in TableColumn cannot be applied to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<org.core.Person, java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<org.core.Person, java.lang.String>>. As its seen my field type is int I do not understand why it keeps saying String. 

//Also I tried it this way. It does not give error msg. But cannot edit into cell when I double click.

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> id = new TableColumn("ID");
        id.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Integer>, ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
            public ObservableValue<Integer> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, Integer> p) {
                return new SimpleIntegerProperty( p.getValue().getId()).asObject();
            }
        });             


        id.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Integer> cell) -> {
                    ((Person) cell.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            cell.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setId(cell.getNewValue());
                });



    personGrid.getColumns().addAll(id);                 

}
```

Comment: expose the id as property on Person and be happy ;)

Comment: `Integer != String`. You cannot use this `forTableColumn` method, iv the column type is not `String`, you need to use the `forTableColumn` method that takes a `StringConverter`. @kleopatra be happy to still have non-compiling code? Your proposal would makes things simpler, but it's unnecessary here bacause of the `onEditCommit` handler and it does not address the code issue.

Comment: @fabian so what? you are right with the code issue which I overlooked - but then I don't even look at code that doesn't use properties, it's always so very very suboptimal that it's a waste of time to consider fixing it ;)

Comment: @kleopatra, you dont even look at the code.then do not make comment. it purposely suboptimal to make sure you do not go through 2 pages of code. I just show where the problem is. Instead of typing comments you could type the solution and not to waste time. not sure you are trying to cause problem or solve the problem

Comment: short != suboptimal (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Whatever your problem _now_ is, it's nothing compared to what to expect if you don't start using properties. Doing stuff with the winds of fx will spare you all the complexity that's needed if you dont, like f.i. you commitHandler - 99% of all use-cases you don't need it. And here you only need it because you don't use properties (repeated on purpose, to hammer it in <g>)

Comment: [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) is part of SO model. It states "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions".  Everyone here is volunteering and should be thanked for their taking the time to help you, weather you like the help or not. Also "it purposely suboptimal to make sure you do not go through 2 pages of code" is not the way to post code. See [mcve].